# Function called when a GameObject doesn't collide with ANYTHING

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a function called when the GameObject is NOT colliding with ANYTHING, as opposed to stopped colliding with one other GameObject. I'd really appreciate a response of some sort, as my questions never seem to get answered. Basically, I wanna do this:

```
 void OnCollisionStay()
 {
     //blah blah blah
 }
 else
 {
     //blah blah blah
 }
```

Edit: I'd be fine and even prefer if it was a function called every frame the GameObject isn't colliding with anything, kinda like a function called every frame that OnCollisionStay isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean value

```
bool isCollision;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(!isCollision)
    {
        //blah blah blah
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    isCollision = true;
}

void OnCollisionExit()
{
    isCollision = false;
}
```

If you want to run the logic after `OnCollisionXXX`, according to the [script lifecycle flowchart](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), you can start a coroutine returns `WaitForFixedUpdate` from `FixedUpdate`.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitForFixedUpdateCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator WaitForFixedUpdateCoroutine()
{
    yield return WaitForFixedUpdate();

    if(!isCollision)
    {
        //blah blah blah
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will post the same answer I gave you on Unity Answers for anyone else looking for the answer on Stackoverflow:

Use a data set to track the objects currently colliding with your object.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    private HashSet<int> collidingGameObjects = new HashSet<int>();

    private void OnCollisionEnter( Collision collision )
    {
        collidingGameObjects.Add( collision.gameObject.GetInstanceID() );
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit( Collision collision )
    {
        collidingGameObjects.Remove( collision.gameObject.GetInstanceID() );
    }

    // Clear the list in OnDisable because `OnCollisionExit` is not called
    // when object is disabled
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        collidingGameObjects.Clear();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if( collidingGameObjects.Count == 0 )
        {
            Debug.Log( "I am not colliding with anything" );
        }
    }
}
```